# C# - Having Problems with Reading XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hi I'm reading in an XML document like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSYMBOL xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SYMBOL Code="AA.P" Name="Alcoa Inc Pf 3.75" />
<SYMBOL Code="AADR" Name="Wcm Bny Focused Growth Adr ETF" />
<SYMBOL Code="AAU" Name="Almaden Minerals" />
<SYMBOL Code="AAVX" Name="Etracs Daily Short 1 Month S&amp;P" />
</ArrayOfSYMBOL>
```

How Would I go about putting the data into a 2D string Array With SYMBOL Then Name.

Comment: I take it you mean "Code", then "Name"

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using something more structured like a list of `Symbol` classes:

```
class Symbol
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var symbols = doc.Descendants("SYMBOL")
                 .Select(x => new Symbol 
                  { 
                    Code = (string)x.Attribute("Code"), 
                    Name = (string)x.Attribute("Name") 
                  })
                 .ToList();
```

This approach has the advantage that you can access individual symbols in a much more easy-to-read and understandable way - instead of accessing an index in an array which is error-prone you can use appropriately named properties of a strongly typed class, i.e. writing out all symbols you found could be:

```
foreach (var symbol in symbols)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol: {0} = {1}", symbol.Code, symbol.Name);
}
```

If you were just looking for a way to look up a symbol's name given its code you also could use `ToDictionary()`:

```
var symbolMap = doc.Descendants("SYMBOL")
                   .ToDictionary( x=> (string)x.Attribute("Code"), 
                                  x=> (string)x.Attribute("Name"));

Console.WriteLine("Name for symbol {0} is {1}", "AA.P", symbolMap["AA.P"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SYMBOL
{
    [XmlAttribute("Code")]            
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SYMBOL[]));
SYMBOL[] symbols = (SYMBOL[])xml.Deserialize(aFileStream);
```